# why it dumped stack twice when my linux driver failed at the second time while first time being insmod ran normally

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, stack-trace, sysfs

i started learning linux driver a few days ago and i write a simple driver.fisrt i insmod my driver ,it showed it runs well ,and normal when i rmmod. but when i insmod it again, console log showed "killed", and then i use dmesg. The kernel log showed twice stackdump which surprised me so that i don't how to debug(use printk (●'◡'●)).
Many times tried on search machine, i got nothing. so i throwed it here, needing your guys help very very desperate. i truely wanna know why it failed at second time, why stackdump happened twice and how could i fix this driver. thanks very very much!
my vm linux kernel version is : 5.13.0
driver code is here:

```
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/export.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kobject.h>

static ssize_t my_file_show(struct device *dev,
 struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    return snprintf(buf, 64, "%s", __func__);
}

static ssize_t my_file_store(struct device *dev,
 struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count)
{   
    pr_info("going to my_file_store\n");
    return count;
}
static DEVICE_ATTR(my_file, 0664, my_file_show, my_file_store);
static int my_devid = -1;
static struct class *my_class = NULL;
static struct device *my_device = NULL;

static int __init my_init(void){
    pr_info("going to %s\n", __func__);
    int ret = 0;
    
    ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&my_devid, 0, 1, "my_devid");
    if(ret < 0){
        my_devid = -1;
        pr_err("[%s,%d]alloc_chrdev_region failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        goto FAULT;
    }
    pr_info("my devid %d\n", my_devid);
    
    my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "my_class");
    if(my_class == NULL){
        pr_err("[%s,%d]class_create failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        goto FAULT;
    }
    
    pr_info("[%s,%d]goes here\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    my_device = device_create(my_class, NULL,  my_devid, "%s", "my_dev");
    if(my_device == NULL){
        pr_err("[%s,%d] device_create failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        goto FAULT;
    }
    
    pr_info("[%s,%d]goes here\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    ret = device_create_file(my_device, &dev_attr_my_file);
    if(ret < 0){
        pr_err("sysfs_create_file failed\n");
        goto FAULT;
    }
    pr_info("go to init tail now\n");
    return 0;
FAULT:
    if(my_devid != -1){
        unregister_chrdev_region(my_devid, "my_devid");
        my_devid = -1;
    }
    
    if(my_device != NULL){
        device_destroy(my_class, my_devid);
        my_device = NULL;
    }
        
    if(my_class != NULL){
        class_destroy(my_class);
        my_class = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void  __exit my_exit(void){
    pr_info("going to %s\n", __func__);
    device_remove_file(my_device, &dev_attr_my_file);
    
    if(my_devid != -1){
        unregister_chrdev_region(my_devid, "my_devid");
        my_devid = -1;
    }
    
    if(my_device != NULL){
        device_destroy(my_class, my_devid);
        my_device = NULL;
    }
        
    if(my_class != NULL){
        class_destroy(my_class);
        my_class = NULL;
    }

}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("tid");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

this is dmesg:

```
going to my_init
[87682.699433] my devid 247463936
[87682.700041] [my_init,47]goes here
[87682.706933] [my_init,54]goes here
[87682.706937] go to init tail now
[87704.903499] going to my_exit
[87747.424115] going to my_init
[87747.424385] my devid 262144000
[87747.424418] [my_init,47]goes here
[87747.424784] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/virtual/my_class'
[87747.424989] CPU: 1 PID: 462167 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           OE     5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu
[87747.424992] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 11/12/2020
[87747.425172] Call Trace:
[87747.426055]  dump_stack+0x7d/0x9c
[87747.427617]  sysfs_warn_dup.cold+0x17/0x27
[87747.427889]  sysfs_create_dir_ns+0xb8/0xd0
[87747.428703]  kobject_add_internal+0xbd/0x2b0
[87747.429021]  kobject_add+0x7e/0xb0
[87747.429023]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x37c/0x440
[87747.429671]  get_device_parent.isra.0+0x179/0x1b0
[87747.429943]  device_add+0xe3/0x8e0
[87747.429945]  device_create_groups_vargs+0xd4/0xf0
[87747.429946]  ? 0xffffffffc09b1000
[87747.429948]  device_create+0x49/0x60
[87747.429950]  my_init+0xf0/0x1000 [test]
[87747.430241]  do_one_initcall+0x46/0x1d0
[87747.430632]  ? __cond_resched+0x19/0x30
[87747.430866]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x37c/0x440
[87747.430869]  do_init_module+0x62/0x260
[87747.430898]  load_module+0x125d/0x1440
[87747.431183]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
[87747.431185]  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
[87747.431186]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
[87747.431188]  do_syscall_64+0x61/0xb0
[87747.431260]  ? __x64_sys_newfstat+0x16/0x20
[87747.431361]  ? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
[87747.431363]  ? __x64_sys_lseek+0x1a/0x20
[87747.431380]  ? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
[87747.431382]  ? exc_page_fault+0x8f/0x170
[87747.431383]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
[87747.431385]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
[87747.431386] RIP: 0033:0x7fd6b8d3789d
[87747.431388] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d c3 f5 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[87747.431390] RSP: 002b:00007ffe09073bd8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[87747.431405] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000557d4fa68760 RCX: 00007fd6b8d3789d
[87747.431405] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000557d4db48358 RDI: 0000000000000003
[87747.431406] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007fd6b8e0b260
[87747.431407] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000557d4db48358
[87747.431407] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000557d4fa683d0 R15: 0000000000000000
[87747.431503] kobject_add_internal failed for my_class with -EEXIST, don't try to register things with the same name in the same directory.
[87747.431713] [my_init,54]goes here
[87747.431749] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 000000000000001f
[87747.431765] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[87747.431780] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[87747.431819] PGD 0 P4D 0 
[87747.431821] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
[87747.431823] CPU: 1 PID: 462167 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           OE     5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu
[87747.431825] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 11/12/2020
[87747.431826] RIP: 0010:sysfs_create_file_ns+0x26/0x90
[87747.431829] Code: 9c 0f 1f 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 53 48 83 ec 10 65 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 45 e0 31 c0 48 85 ff 74 5b <48> 83 7f 30 00 48 89 fb 74 51 49 89 f4 48 85 f6 74 49 49 89 d5 48
[87747.431831] RSP: 0018:ffffa39a0406fbe0 EFLAGS: 00010282
[87747.431832] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000027
[87747.431833] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffffc09ae020 RDI: ffffffffffffffef
[87747.431834] RBP: ffffa39a0406fc08 R08: ffff8e77b9e589c0 R09: ffffa39a0406fa18
[87747.431835] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffffffc09ae020
[87747.431836] R13: ffffffffffffffef R14: ffffffffc09ae040 R15: 0000000000000000
[87747.431837] FS:  00007fd6b8bf2540(0000) GS:ffff8e77b9e40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[87747.431838] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[87747.432290] CR2: 000000000000001f CR3: 000000001f4c8005 CR4: 00000000003706e0
[87747.432721] Call Trace:
[87747.432724]  device_create_file+0x42/0x80
[87747.432726]  ? 0xffffffffc09b1000
[87747.432728]  my_init+0x141/0x1000 [test]
[87747.432730]  do_one_initcall+0x46/0x1d0
[87747.432732]  ? __cond_resched+0x19/0x30
[87747.432734]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x37c/0x440
[87747.432737]  do_init_module+0x62/0x260
[87747.432739]  load_module+0x125d/0x1440
[87747.432741]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
[87747.432742]  ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xc2/0x120
[87747.432743]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x1a/0x20
[87747.432745]  do_syscall_64+0x61/0xb0
[87747.432747]  ? __x64_sys_newfstat+0x16/0x20
[87747.432749]  ? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
[87747.432750]  ? __x64_sys_lseek+0x1a/0x20
[87747.432752]  ? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
[87747.432754]  ? exc_page_fault+0x8f/0x170
[87747.432755]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
[87747.432756]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
[87747.432758] RIP: 0033:0x7fd6b8d3789d
[87747.432759] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d c3 f5 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[87747.432760] RSP: 002b:00007ffe09073bd8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[87747.432762] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000557d4fa68760 RCX: 00007fd6b8d3789d
[87747.433030] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000557d4db48358 RDI: 0000000000000003
[87747.433032] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007fd6b8e0b260
[87747.433033] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000557d4db48358
[87747.433033] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000557d4fa683d0 R15: 0000000000000000
[87747.433036] Modules linked in: test(OE+) vsock_loopback vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd rapl vmw_balloon snd_ens1371 snd_ac97_codec gameport ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi joydev input_leds serio_raw snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore vmw_vmci mac_hid sch_fq_codel vmwgfx ttm drm_kms_helper cec rc_core fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt msr nfsd parport_pc auth_rpcgss ppdev nfs_acl lockd lp grace parport drm sunrpc ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic ahci e1000 libahci usbhid hid mptspi mptscsih mptbase crc32_pclmul psmouse scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4 pata_acpi [last unloaded: test]
[87747.433869] CR2: 000000000000001f
[87747.434327] ---[ end trace d7785aaa07b44309 ]---
[87747.434352] RIP: 0010:sysfs_create_file_ns+0x26/0x90
[87747.434357] Code: 9c 0f 1f 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 55 41 54 53 48 83 ec 10 65 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 45 e0 31 c0 48 85 ff 74 5b <48> 83 7f 30 00 48 89 fb 74 51 49 89 f4 48 85 f6 74 49 49 89 d5 48
[87747.434359] RSP: 0018:ffffa39a0406fbe0 EFLAGS: 00010282
[87747.434361] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000027
[87747.434362] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffffc09ae020 RDI: ffffffffffffffef
[87747.434363] RBP: ffffa39a0406fc08 R08: ffff8e77b9e589c0 R09: ffffa39a0406fa18
[87747.434363] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffffffc09ae020
[87747.434364] R13: ffffffffffffffef R14: ffffffffc09ae040 R15: 0000000000000000
[87747.434365] FS:  00007fd6b8bf2540(0000) GS:ffff8e77b9e40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[87747.434366] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[87747.434368] CR2: 000000000000001f CR3: 000000001f4c8005 CR4: 00000000003706e0
```

Comment: `cannot create duplicate filename` suggests that something didn't work in your _exit code.  I notice you are not removing things in the reverse order that you create them.

Comment: Your `my_init` is returning 0 on failure after cleaning up after itself. It should return an error.

Comment: Your `my_exit` assigns `my_devid = -1;` and then calls `device_destroy(my_class, my_devid);`. That will try and destroy a non-existent device. That probably leaves an outstanding reference count on `my_class`.

Comment: @stark thanks a lot! because of ignorance of logic relations between kernel objects,i did not remove things in the reverse order and just took actions by their property. thus chaos emerged. thanks again, your answer helps a lot for my code.

Comment: @Ian Abbott thanks a lot for your help. i will be more careful next time.

Comment: @Ian Abbott thanks very very much !